# Is there a need for a public landing page?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, user-experience

I'm working on building a platform (multiple apps under one product) and I'm wondering if there is a technical benefit for a public landing page.  I'm hoping "public landing page" is a reasonable description of what I'm talking about...

To give an example, Google Photos (http://photos.google.com) and Google Drive (http://drive.google.com), both have similar pages for an unauthenticated user to initiate the login process.  Once initiated (by a button on either public landing page), that login process uses OAuth and redirects to a centralized auth server (in this case, http://accounts.google.com), passing all the necessary client, redirect URI, etc. info in the query string.  The user is then redirected back to the correct app upon successful authentication.

Google may be using these type of pages to do additional marketing, but for a "normal" app, is there a technical benefit to a public landing page?

ps. I was considering posting this in ux.stackoverflow.com, but I'm interested in the answer from a technical perspective rather than a user experience one.

Answer (score 2):

I will prefer to have a default landing page for each application for the following reasons:

1. To give some introduction to the application for first time users.
   It makes them a bit more comfortable than a situation where they are
   taken straight to the login page.
2. If the authentication server (e.g. accounts.google.com) is down or
   inaccessible, then we can put up a nice message for the users and
   hide the login button. It creates a much better user experience.
3. If applications are publicly accessible web apps then search engine
   crawlers cannot read and add any information about the web app in
   their database and the app becomes non searchable. A sitemap xml can
   be helpful for crawlers but content pages always rank higher.